# Oracle Execution of PL/SQL block

Tags: plsql

```
Declare
  a number := 5; b number := null; c number := 10;
Begin
  if a > b AND a < c then
    a := c * a;
  end if;
End;
```

What will be the value of 'a' after execution ?

Why is the answer 5? Please explain

Answer (score 3):

Null is not a value. Any comparison of a number to null will result in null. And although it doesn't return true or false in your statement, getting a null result with `a > b` is equivalent to returning false. Your `AND` criteria is not met; `a` is not greater than `null`. Therefore `a` remains equal to 5.

Comment: Nit picking a bit: 'a' will be undeclared after the execution - it is local to block :)